# Can Trello provide the (static) number of a card's position on a list?

Tags: trello, trello-lists

Let's say that we are ranking the top 100 safest American cities. One of the cities is beginning to outrank the city ahead of it. Is it possible to move the safer city up in rank, and see the numerical position that the card is now ranking in without editing the card. I understand that Trello numbers cards. But I am more concerned with the position that the card moves into. I would like the list to be dynamic but the list positions (1-100) to be static. Any ideas?